# PHPMyadmin backslash on query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I cannot run sql queries to phpMyAdmin because every time I try to run a query (Update or Insert ) backslashes are added before quotes or double .

Example:

```
update bareme set code_fam='loa' WHERE code=159
```

I get the following error message:

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 31
STR: =\
SQL: `update`bareme`set`code_fam`=\'loa\' WHERE`code`=159`

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'loa\' WHERE `code`=159' at line 1

```
magic_quotes_gpc=on;
magic_quotes_runtime=off;
magic_quotes_sybase=off;
```

Comment: You already are close to the answer: turn `magic_quotes_gpc` off

Comment: thanks but i can't change my php.ini in yahoo hosting, i tested in my localhost when I set magic_quotes_gpc=on, the insert and the update still working without add backslash